# Filter nested sorting in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a document with a nested structure the nested object has an `assignment_name` and a `due_date`:

The mapping

```
{
  "goal": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          // lot's of other fields here ...
          "steps": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "assignment_name": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "due_date": {
                "type": "date"
              }
              // lots of other fields here
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to:

1. Filter all document that have a specific assignment_name (e.g.`user_a`)
2. Sort the result by the next due_date, not taking other assignements into account.

This query gives me random result (no sortings):

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"steps",
                  "query":{  
                     "term":{  
                        "steps.assignment_name":"user_a"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      {  
         "steps.due_date":{  
            "order":"asc",
            "nested":{  
               "path":"steps",
               "filter":{  
                  "term":{  
                     "steps.assignment_name":"user_a"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "from":0,
   "size":25
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to ensure that datatype for `steps` field is `nested`. Then you have to use [nested sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting) to sort documents based on a nested document field.

The query would be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "steps",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "steps.assignment_name": "user_a"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "steps.due_date": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "steps",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "steps.assignment_name": "user_a"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The catch above is to use the same filter in sort as used in the main query to filter the documents. This ensures that the correct nested document's field value is considered to sort the documents.

Comment: Hm. That does not work. I get zero results with the `.keyword` postfix and random (not sorted) results without it.

Comment: @shredding Can you add mapping of index to the question?

Comment: The actual mapping is somewhat different (as the problem was easier to explain with comments, but i will update accordingly) in a sec!

Comment: Updated. I now copied the mapping and actual query. Sorry for me failing at trying to give a simplified example.

Comment: Is there a possibility that a single document has more than one nested documents with `steps.assignment_name` having value as `user_a`?

Comment: That is actually the idea. It can have n steps with various assignments and I want to have the next one.

Comment: It is really weird, as it's not random. I have a unit test and it works roughly 19 out of 20 times.

Comment: Okay, it's seems to be not random. I increased the `sleep` command I have after committing to the index to one second and it's now working. So it may be that there was just some problem with syncing in my unit test. Thank you very much.

Comment: ... hm. or not, it rougly breaks every 1/30, but maybe that is a sync problem.

Comment: Seems like you are querying before the index gets refreshed.

Comment: Is there some way how I can tell if the index is refreshed? I'm using flush_index at the moment and pythons `sleep`.

Comment: Look at [refresh index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html). This should be used with care for production cluster. Though its ok to use for dev/test env and UTs.

Comment: Yeah, in production I'm fine with a delay. I added 1 sec of sleep, followed by a refresh and was able to run my unit test 100times in a row. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How to include another filtering criteria for sorting?